# image or file update php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following update.php code. I can update all of the fields however I have to upload an new image or file each time I try updating text fields. All of my images are located in 'downloads' folder. I still want to be able to keep the same [file][name] if I only want to update other fields. Please help. Database is only saving the text.

```
     <?php
        session_start();

    include 'config.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location:index.php');
        exit();
    }


     ?>

       <?php 

        require 'database.php';

    //Checks the incident by id 

    $id = null;
     if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    }

    if ( null==$id ) {
    header("Location: incidents.php");
     }



    if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    // keep track validation errors




    // keep track post values
    $officer = $_POST['officer'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $complaint = $_POST['complaint'];
    $injured_name = $_POST['injured_name'];
    $owner_name = $_POST['owner_name'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];       

    //To be able to upload file to 'uploads/' folder all file related files. 
    //
    if(isset($_POST['btn-upload']))
       {    


    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $target_path = "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB
    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);



     }
     else
     {


    $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
    $target_path = "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    $folder="uploads/";

    $uploadfile = $folder . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
   echo $uploadfile;
    // new file size in KB
    $new_size = $file_size/1024;  
    // new file size in KB
    // make file name in lower case
    $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
    // make file name in lower case

    $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);


      }



        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "UPDATE incidents SET officer = ?, date = ?, complaint =?, injured_name = ?, owner_name =?, description =?, file =?, type =?, size =? WHERE id =?";
        $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute(array($officer, $date, $complaint, $injured_name, $owner_name, $description, $final_file, $file_type, $new_size, $id));
        Database::disconnect();
        header("Location: incidents.php");

     }


         else {
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM incidents where id = ?";

    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    $data = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $officer = $data['officer'];
    $date = $data['date'];
    $complaint = $data['complaint'];
    $injured_name = $data['injured_name'];
    $owner_name = $data['owner_name'];
    $description = $data['description'];
    $file = $data['file'];






        Database::disconnect();
     }

        ?>



      <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
      <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Update incident</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Slick &amp; clean CSS3 Forms Pack" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <!-- Forms stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/slick_qfb.css" media="screen" />
    <!-- / Forms stylesheet -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo/demo.css" media="screen" />
    <!--[if IE 9]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/placeholder.js"></script>
     <![endif]-->
     <script type="text/javascript">''</script>


         </head>
        <body>
        <div id="page">

    <!-- Start Demo page title -->
    <div class="demo">

    <h1>&#x25C2; </h1>
    </div>
    <!-- End demo page title -->



     <section id="slick">
    <!-- Social buttons -->



     <div class="sb">
     <a href="incidents.php">Home Page</a>
        <!--
        <a href="#" class="fb entypo-thumbs-up"><span class="slick-tip right">Like us on Facebook</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="gc entypo-google-circles"><span class="slick-tip right">Find us in Circles</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="tw entypo-twitter"><span class="slick-tip right">Follow us on Twitter</span></a>
        -->
    </div>

    <!-- Questionnaire form -->
    <div class="questionnaire-form">            
        <!-- Title -->
        <div class="title">Update Incident</div> 
        <!-- Intro text -->
        <p class="intro">Please Update this case by entering the information</p>
        <!-- Form fields -->
        <form action="update.php?id=<?php echo $id?>"  id="questionnaire" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <!-- Left block -->
            <div class="w-47 mr-6">
                <!-- Subject input -->
                <!-- <div class="field">
                    <select name="subject" id="subject" class="grayed" onClick="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" class="disabled">Subject</option>
                        <option value="Website design">1. Website design</option>
                        <option value="Graphic design">2. Graphic design</option>
                        <option value="App development">3. App development</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="arrow-select"></div>
                    <svg id="arrow-select-svg"></svg>
                    <span class="entypo-book icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Choose subject</span>
                </div> -->
                <!-- Officer' Full name -->
                <div class="field">
                    <input name="officer" placeholder="Officer on Duty" type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo !empty($officer)?$officer:'';?>" required />
                    <span class="entypo-user icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Officer on Duty</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Incident date -->
                <div class="field">

                    <input name="date" placeholder="Time Incident Happened" type="text" id="datetimepicker" value="<?php echo !empty($date)?$date:'';?>" required />
                    <span class="entypo-briefcase icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Time Incident Happened</span>
                </div>
                <!-- Type Of Animal Complaint -->
                <div class="field">
                    <input name="complaint" placeholder="Type of Animal Complaint" type="text" id="complaint" value="<?php echo !empty($complaint)?$complaint:'';?>"required />
                    <span class="entypo-monitor icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Type of Animal Complaint</span>
                </div>
                <!--

                <div class="field">
                    <input name="phone" placeholder="(304) 111 1111" type="tel" id="phone" required />
                    <span class="entypo-mobile icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left"></span>
                </div>

                -->
                <!-- Injured Info -->
                <div class="field">
                    <input name="injured_name" placeholder="Injured Person's Full Name" type="text" id="injured_name" value="<?php echo !empty($injured_name)?$injured_name:'';?>" required />
                    <span class="entypo-user icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Injured Person's Full Name</span>
                </div>

                <div class="field">
                    <input name="owner_name" placeholder="Animal Owner's Full Name" type="text" id="owner_name" value="<?php echo !empty($owner_name)?$owner_name:'';?>" required />
                    <span class="entypo-user icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Animal Owner's Full Name</span>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- Right block -->
            <div class="w-47">
                <!-- Subject input -->
                <!--
                <div class="field">
                    <select name="service" id="service" class="grayed" onClick="this.className=this.options[this.selectedIndex].className">
                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected" class="disabled">Complaint Type</option>
                        <option value="Distressed Animal">1. Distressed Animal</option>
                        <option value="Animal Byte">2. Animal Byte</option>
                        <option value="Complaint about an animal">3. Complaint About an Animal</option>
                    </select>
                    <div id="arrow-select"></div>
                    <svg id="arrow-select-svg"></svg>
                    <span class="entypo-cog icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Complaint Type</span>
                </div>
                -->


                <!-- Upload Picture-->
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="upload" for="uploads">
                        <div class="btn">

                            <input name="file" placeholder="file upload" type="file" id="file" value="<?php echo $target_path; ?>"/></div>

               <div> </div>

                  </label>
                </div>
                <div></div>
                <!-- Overview input -->
                <div class="field">
                    <textarea name="description" type="text"  ROWS="5" COLS="25"  placeholder="Alert Description" ><?php echo !empty($description)?$description:''; ?></textarea>
                    <span class="entypo-comment icon"></span>
                    <span class="slick-tip left">Describe Animal Incident in detail</span>
                </div>
                <div class="w-47 mt-5">
                    <label class="reset" for="reset">
                        <span class="entypo-arrows-ccw">Reset Form</span>

                    </label>
                    <input type="reset" id="reset" value="">
                </div>
                <!-- Send button -->

                <input type="submit" class="send" form="questionnaire"  />
            </div>
        </form>

        <!-- / Form fields -->
           </div>
        <!-- / Animal Control form -->
           </section>

        </div>
        </body>
           </html>
```

Comment: if file in form do file things, otherwise dont

Comment: What do you mean by do file things only?

Comment: if no image file is uploaded you want to skip all the file related code - and keep the original image, if image is uploaded do all the file related code.